# loopback model access in custom js file

Tags: javascript, node.js, loopbackjs

i want to access a model name userRegistration in my custom js file but every time its showing undefined and shows this error

TypeError: Cannot call method 'findOne' of undefined

please Check code

```
var loopback = require('loopback');
var app  = loopback();
var nodemailer = require("nodemailer");
var smtpTransport = require("nodemailer-smtp-transport");
var path=require('path');
var fs=require('fs');
var Handlebars = require('handlebars');


exports.mailToUser=function(req,res,next){
var userNotification = app.models.UserNotification;
var userregister = app.models.UserRegistration;
userregister.findOne({where:{email:email}},function(err,userobj){
 if(err){
   next()
 }

  })



 }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't use `var app  = loopback();`

If you want to access to `app` you can require your `server.js` or some other ways existed. The simple one is requiring `server`

Comment: after  require server.js can i use app like server.app

Comment: @pankajmalik no. `var app = require('path to server.js');`

Comment: i am using like this  

          var server=require("../server");
          var app=server.loopback()

         var userregister = app.models.UserRegistration

        userregister.findOne({where:{email:email}},function(err,userobj){})

but its not working

Comment: @pankajmalik You required wrongly. Please just change requiring app line like this : `var app = require('../server');`

Comment: The other lines are correct. Just change the require app line

Comment: @pankajmalik cool. If question is answered please kindly accept my answer